# div other site-page add it inside a div tag or iframe tag in my site

Tags: jquery, parsing, html

I want the Terms from an external Site (inside a div) get html code/data and add them inside a div tag in my site... I guess I must get the html page parse the page get the div contents and add the to my site...is it permitted this from other site not same server?

Can you provide some step hints?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with an iframe inside the div on your site.

```
<iframe src="http://www.theothersite.com/terms.html"></iframe>
```

If you want to actually scrape the contents of the other site, you could use cURL or something similar.  There are tons of Perl, PHP, etc examples of screen scraping.  Here's one for reference: http://devtrench.com/posts/screen-scrape-with-php-curl

Comment: what if not want whole page appear from external page (to my page) but ONLY a div contents from it?